# Script connect to MS Sql database inside WebMatrix

Tags: php, sql-server, webmatrix

The simple instance of connection to database doesn't work:

```
<?php
mssql_connect('.\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'mypass');
echo 'test';
?>
```

The page shows nothing but without mssql_connect instruction it echo the string fine.
I can't even add 'die' instruction to view error log - happens nothing again.
Whats wrong? I would connect to local integrated db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of PHP are you using. To my knowledge mssql_connect was removed in PHP 5.3. A solution to that is PDO connection.